# Declaring object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Need to declare a object type. Getting below mentioned error:

```
 type CarKeys = "mercedes" | "mercedes-sedan" | "mercedes-hatch";

    interface Car { color: string; } 

    const KEY_MAP = { mercedes: 'mercedes', mercedes_sedan: 'mercedes-sedan', mercedes_hatch: 'mercedes-hatch'};

        const carType:Record<CarKeys, Car> = {
         [KEY_MAP.mercedes]:{ color: 'red'},
         [KEY_MAP.mercedes_sedan]: {color: 'yellow'},
         [KEY_MAP.mercedes_hatch]: {color: 'black'}
        };
```

TypeScript is throwing following error :

> Type'{[x: string]: { color: string }}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record': mercedes, mercedes-sedan, mercedes-hatch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things, first you wrote `type CarKeys = "mercedes" | "mercedes_sedan" | "mercedes_hatch"`, all with **underscore** but values in `KEY_MAP` have **hyphen**, that's a mismatch you might want to fix.

Second, by default TS will infer `typeof KEY_MAP` to be `{ mercedes: string; ... }` instead of `{ mercedes: "mercedes", ... }`.

This means `typeof [KEY_MAP.mercedes]` is actually `string`, not the `"mercedes"` string literal, thus typeof `carType` is actually `{ [key: string]: Car }`, that's why the error.

To fix it, you can add `as const` to the end of `KEY_MAP`:

```
const KEY_MAP = {
  mercedes: 'mercedes',
  mercedes_sedan: 'mercedes-sedan',
  mercedes_hatch: 'mercedes-hatch'
} as const;
```

Or, you can turn it to a `enum`

```
enum KEY_MAP {
  mercedes = 'mercedes',
  mercedes_sedan = 'mercedes-sedan',
  mercedes_hatch ='mercedes-hatch'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your code, the values in `KEY_MAP` do not actually match the values specified in `CarKeys`. Also, the semi-colons in `carType` need to be commas.

To fix the problem at hand you can use `as const`. In your code the resolved type of `KEY_MAP` is:

```
const KEY_MAP: {
    mercedes: string;
    mercedes_sedan: string;
    mercedes_hatch: string;
}
```

Specify it like this:

```
const KEY_MAP = {
    mercedes: 'mercedes',
    mercedes_sedan: 'mercedes_sedan',
    mercedes_hatch: 'mercedes_hatch'
} as const;
```

Then the resolved type will be:

```
const KEY_MAP: {
    readonly mercedes: "mercedes";
    readonly mercedes_sedan: "mercedes_sedan";
    readonly mercedes_hatch: "mercedes_hatch";
}
```

Which should compile.

Comment: @Andreas: Right, the semicolons need to be replaced with commas. Forgot to note that i fixed that as well in my code...

Answer (score 3):

First of all when using TypeScript you don't need to use Key -> Value map + String literal types. You can choose one of both, as it will ensure the type safety. Also approach with using Enum instead of standard JS object will be more appropriate as it will solve and the value and the type in one language construct. Consider the solution with using Enum only:

```
interface Car { color: string; } 

enum KEY_MAP {
    mercedes = 'mercedes',
    mercedes_sedan = 'mercedes_sedan',
    mercedes_hatch = 'mercedes_hatch'
}

const carType: Record<KEY_MAP, Car> = {
    [KEY_MAP.mercedes]:{ color: 'red'},
    [KEY_MAP.mercedes_sedan]: {color: 'yellow'},
    [KEY_MAP.mercedes_hatch]: {color: 'black'}
}
```

Also solution with only string literal is fully valid and type safe. Consider:

```
type CarKeys = "mercedes" | "mercedes_sedan" | "mercedes_hatch";

interface Car { color: string; } 

const carType: Record<CarKeys, Car> = {
    mercedes:{ color: 'red'},
    mercedes_sedan: {color: 'yellow'},
    mercedes_hatch: {color: 'black'}
} // carType cannot be created with wrong key or value type
```

String literal type should not be considered as 'magic string' as it is watched by compiler and type safe. We don't need to create some middle structure to use it directly.

And last not least. You can fix your implementation directly by specifing correct type for KEY_MAP.

```
type CarKeys = "mercedes" | "mercedes_sedan" | "mercedes_hatch";

interface Car { color: string; } 

const KEY_MAP: { [P in CarKeys]: P } = { mercedes: 'mercedes', mercedes_sedan: 'mercedes_sedan', mercedes_hatch: 'mercedes_hatch'};

const carType:Record<CarKeys, Car> = {
    [KEY_MAP.mercedes]:{ color: 'red'},
    [KEY_MAP.mercedes_sedan]: {color: 'yellow'},
    [KEY_MAP.mercedes_hatch]: {color: 'black'}
}; // no issues
```

The core thing is `{ [P in CarKeys]: P }`. We are saying that our object has exact single item from `CarKeys` as a key and as a value.

Comment: @gaurav-soni can you take a look on this answer. I think it is answering you question on multiple levels. Thank you.